# Wildcard DNS resolution failed when adding TXT record

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a DNS setup with IBM SOFTLAYER with below setup

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ns1.softlayer.com. support.softlayer.com. (
                       2018110900        ; Serial
                       7200              ; Refresh
                       600               ; Retry
                       1728000           ; Expire
                       43200)            ; Minimum

@                      86400    IN NS    ns1.softlayer.com.
@                      86400    IN NS    ns2.softlayer.com.


@                      60       IN TXT   v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
google._domainkey      86400    IN TXT   v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=AB
_dmarc.mydomain.com.  86400    IN TXT   v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; pct=100; rua=mailto:support@mydomain.com
*                      900      IN CNAME mydomain.com.
devadmin               86400    IN CNAME admin.mydomain.com.
ftp                    86400    IN CNAME admin.mydomain.com.
@                      86400    IN A     100.100.100.100
admin                  86400    IN A     200.200.200.200
```

This setup works fine and I can resolve queries like mydomain.com, devmedia.mydomain.com, x.devmedia.mydomain.com

The issue arises when I add another TXT record for Lets Encrypt domain validation.

```
_acme-challenge.devmedia 60       IN TXT   txttestrest
```

Once added, domains with devmedia.mydomain.com stop resolving.
Is this normal behavior or some bug in DNS. 
Do I need to add `devmedia.mydomain.com` explicitly in my DNS or there is some other way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CNAME records are not allowed to co-exist with other records. Since you have a CNAME defined for *devmedia*, you can't create a *acme-challenge.devmedia*. So either you need to change devmedia to an A record, or handle it some other way.

It might work to create *acme-challenge.admin* instead, since that is where the CNAME points, but I am not sure if they will actually check that way.

Comment: I do not have any explicit CNAME for devmedia. Do you mean *  -  CNAME is causing the issue ?

Comment: Yeah, the wildcard will be the issue.